# asp.net mvc - How to order the Virtual Item in entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

For example I have 2 models that *Topic* and *Comment*.
1 Topic can have some Comment, so in my Topics class I have an ICollection feid:

```
public class Topic
{
    //........................
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

And I call it by this stament:

```
var topic = db.Topics.Include("Comments").Single(d => d.TopicId == someid)
```

The code will load for me all the *Comment* thats belong to my current *Topic*, so I can print all my comment out by this code:

```
@foreach (var comment in topic.Comments)
{
    <div>@comment.CommentContent</div><hr />
}
```

The issue is I want to re-oder my Comments list, but I donot know HOW! Please some one show me the right way!
Thanks all of you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@foreach (var comment in topic.Comments.OrderBy(c=>c.PropertyYouWantToOrderBy))
{
<div>@comment.CommentContent</div><hr />
}
```

Comment: When I do as you say, I got a Compiler Error Message: CS1977: Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type

Comment: are your view strongly typed? is "topic" dynamic ?

Comment: No! In fact I too lazy so I have set _ViewBag.topic = db.Topics.Include("Comments").Single(d => d.TopicId == someid);_ so I guest now I should do it as the traditional way?!

Comment: dont use ViewBag for domain model objects... bad bad nvcnvn ! :) create a ViewModel